Golly can't find Pillow module
I'm trying to use the cellular automata program Golly and I downloaded a plugin to allow me to save my generations as image files. Whenever I try to run the plugin however, I get the following message:

I have no clue what could be causing this. I've cd'd to multiple directories and ran pip install Pillow multiple times. Pillow is clearly installed on my machine. Why isn't Golly recognizing it? I have Python v3.12 installed and I've downloaded the latest version of Golly that supports Python3. OS is Windows 10.

maybe you have two Pythons installed and you install pillow in one Python but it runs code with other Python. But Pythons don't share modules.

I checked all installed python packages with 'dir site.py /s' and the only one that I have installed is 3.12. I even uninstalled and reinstalled pillow and the plugin still doesn't work. So it's clearly not that, unless I wasn't checking correctly.

maybe in Golly you could run code import sys ; print( sys.executable ) to see /full/path/to/python and later use it (in console/terminal) to install modules /full/path/to/python -m pip install pillow

eventually you can find plugin on your disk and edit it - in except you can try use something like this import pip pip.main(["install", "pillow"]) and again from PIL import Image - and maybe it will install pillow when first from PIL import Image raise error
